# Android IAB Error - Authentication required

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I got a problem testing In App Billing ()v3 in my app, I can't buy anything with test accounts. It always shows me a Play Store dialog with

```
"Error Authentication is required. You must log in with your Google Account"
```

I can only buy the reserved item "android.test.purchased" without any problem and consume it.

IAB start:

```
private static final int REQ_CODE_BUY = 51667;
    private static final String buyFile = "bought";

    private Activity activity;
    private ProgressDialog pD;
    private IInAppBillingService mService;
    private ServiceConnection mServiceConn = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            mService = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, 
                IBinder service) {
            mService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(service);
        }
    };

    public IABHelper(Activity activity, ProgressDialog pD){
        this.activity = activity;
        this.pD = pD;
    }

    public void start(){
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
        serviceIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
        activity.bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    public void destroy(){
        if (mService != null) {
            activity.unbindService(mServiceConn);
        }   
    }
```

IAB buy and consume:

```
public void buy(String sku){
        try {
            Bundle buyIntentBundle = mService.getBuyIntent(3, activity.getPackageName(), sku, "inapp", devPayload);
            //Bundle buyIntentBundle = mService.getBuyIntent(3, activity.getPackageName(), "android.test.purchased", "inapp", devPayload);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");
            if(pendingIntent != null){
                activity.startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), REQ_CODE_BUY, new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0));
                pD.show();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(activity, R.string.error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void consume(final String purchaseToken){
        Thread consumeThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    int response = mService.consumePurchase(3, activity.getPackageName(), purchaseToken);
                    //int response = mService.consumePurchase(3, activity.getPackageName(), "inapp:com.mumble.artplace:android.test.purchased");
                    Log.d("response", Integer.toString(response));
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        consumeThread.start();
    }
```

Handle buy response:

```
    public void resolveResponse(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if(requestCode == REQ_CODE_BUY){
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                int responseCode = data.getIntExtra("RESPONSE_CODE", 0);
                String purchaseData = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA");
                String dataSignature = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE");

                JSONObject jData;
                try {
                    if(responseCode == 0){
                        jData = new JSONObject(purchaseData);
                        String purchaseToken = jData.getString("purchaseToken");
                        String developerPayload = jData.getString("developerPayload");
                        if(developerPayload.equals(devPayload))){
                            consume(purchaseToken);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                pD.dismiss();
            }
            else{
                if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){
                    pD.dismiss();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When this happens and i click "OK" it only returns a responseCode RESULT_CANCEL and an Intent with empty extras.
I already tried to remove all accounts from my device and leaving only the developer one, only the test ones and tried with other phones without any success. I really don't know where I am wrong...
Please help me, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Soomla IAB error while purchasing in Game on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934552/soomla-iab-error-while-purchasing-in-game-on-android/27954078#27954078)
this was my question, i think is the same problem, so ,
  the problem is on the Google developer console, in order to buy you must publish the apk ,even if it is a beta or Alpha, and after ,you can test with testers approved accounts.

Comment: My app is published and it was working fine but now its making problem. Any solution will be apreciated

Answer (score 0):

In my case It was mistake of product Id, The product Id from Play-store and in app SKU_NAME should be same for in app billing.

It is not mention properly in iab sample project which one is productId 

i.e **SKU_GAS ="gas"** and **SKU_PREMIUM="premium"** in project

then 

**"gas"** and **"premium"** must be available on play-store **as productId**.