# Android In-app Purchase V3 Error: Authentication is required

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am implementing `Google In-app Purchase V3` and followed all steps stated over [here](https://help.gamesalad.com/hc/en-us/articles/203536123-7-6-In-App-Purchases-IAP-for-Google-Play) as well in official documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html). I have uploaded my app in Google Playstore for `Alpha Testing` and I have downloaded that from playstore URL into my real device but it giving me error

> Error
>
> Authentication is required. You need to sign into your Google Account.

[image]

My code for In-app purchase is here:

```
public class BuyPointsFragment extends Fragment
//In app Billing variable start

    // Debug tag, for logging
        static final String TAG = "com.myApp";

        // Does the user have the premium upgrade?
        boolean mIsPremium = false;

        // Does the user have an active subscription to the infinite gas plan?
        boolean mSubscribedToInfiniteGas = false;

        // SKUs for our products: the premium upgrade (non-consumable) and gas
        // (consumable)
        static final String SKU_PREMIUM = "premium";
        static final String SKU_GAS = "gas";

        // SKU for our subscription (infinite gas)
        static final String SKU_INFINITE_GAS = "infinite_gas";

        // (arbitrary) request code for the purchase flow
        static final int RC_REQUEST = 10001;

        // Graphics for the gas gauge
        static int[] TANK_RES_IDS = {};

        // How many units (1/4 tank is our unit) fill in the tank.
        static final int TANK_MAX = 4;

        // Current amount of gas in tank, in units
        int mTank;

        // The helper object
        IabHelper mHelper;
        
    

    //In app billing variable end



@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //inapp  load game data
            loadData();
            
            String base64EncodedPublicKey = "Base64Key from publisher account";

            // Some sanity checks to see if the developer (that's you!) really
            // followed the
            // instructions to run this sample (don't put these checks on your app!)
            if (base64EncodedPublicKey.contains("CONSTRUCT_YOUR")) {
                throw new RuntimeException(
                        "Please put your app's public key in MainActivity.java. See README.");
            }
            if (getActivity().getPackageName().startsWith("com.myApp.activity")) {
                throw new RuntimeException(
                        "Please change the sample's package name! See README.");
            }

            // Create the helper, passing it our context and the public key to
            // verify signatures with
            Log.d(TAG, "Creating IAB helper.");
            mHelper = new IabHelper(getActivity(), base64EncodedPublicKey);

            // enable debug logging (for a production application, you should set
            // this to false).
            mHelper.enableDebugLogging(true);

            // Start setup. This is asynchronous and the specified listener
            // will be called once setup completes.
            Log.d(TAG, "Starting setup.");
            mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
                public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Setup finished.");

                    if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                        // Oh noes, there was a problem.
                        complain(getString(R.string.problem_setting_inapp_billing) + result);
                        return;
                    }

                    // Have we been disposed of in the meantime? If so, quit.
                    if (mHelper == null)
                        return;

                    // IAB is fully set up. Now, let's get an inventory of stuff we
                    // own.
                    Log.d(TAG, "Setup successful. Querying inventory.");
                    mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
                    
                    
                    
                }
            });

            //In app billing code end here
    }
```

//In app billing methods start here

```
public void inappCall(){
    
    setWaitScreen(true);
    Log.d(TAG, "Launching purchase flow for gas.");

    /*
     * TODO: for security, generate your payload here for verification. See
     * the comments on verifyDeveloperPayload() for more info. Since this is
     * a SAMPLE, we just use an empty string, but on a production app you
     * should carefully generate this.
     */
    String payload = "";

    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(getActivity(), SKU_GAS, RC_REQUEST,
            mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);
}

    // updates UI to reflect model
        public void updateUi() {
            // update the car color to reflect premium status or lack thereof
            // ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.free_or_premium)).setImageResource(mIsPremium
            // ? R.drawable.premium : R.drawable.free);

            // "Upgrade" button is only visible if the user is not premium
            // findViewById(R.id.upgrade_button).setVisibility(mIsPremium ?
            // View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);

            // "Get infinite gas" button is only visible if the user is not
            // subscribed yet
            // (R.id.infinite_gas_button).setVisibility(mSubscribedToInfiniteGas ?
            // View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);

            // update gas gauge to reflect tank status
            if (mSubscribedToInfiniteGas) {
                // ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.gas_gauge)).setImageResource(R.drawable.gas_inf);
            } else {
                int index = mTank >= TANK_RES_IDS.length ? TANK_RES_IDS.length - 1
                        : mTank;
                // ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.gas_gauge)).setImageResource(TANK_RES_IDS[index]);
            }
        }

        // Enables or disables the "please wait" screen.
        void setWaitScreen(boolean set) {
            // findViewById(R.id.screen_main).setVisibility(set ? View.GONE :
            // View.VISIBLE);
            // findViewById(R.id.screen_wait).setVisibility(set ? View.VISIBLE :
            // View.GONE);
        }

        void complain(String message) {
            Log.e(TAG, "**** TrivialDrive Error: " + message);
            alert("Error: " + message);
        }

        void alert(String message) {
            AlertDialog.Builder bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            bld.setMessage(message);
            bld.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
            Log.d(TAG, "Showing alert dialog: " + message);
            bld.create().show();
        }

        void saveData() {

            /*
             * WARNING: on a real application, we recommend you save data in a
             * secure way to prevent tampering. For simplicity in this sample, we
             * simply store the data using a SharedPreferences.
             */

            SharedPreferences.Editor spe = getActivity().getPreferences(getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            spe.putInt("tank", mTank);
            spe.commit();
            Log.d(TAG, "Saved data: tank = " + String.valueOf(mTank));
        }

        void loadData() {
            SharedPreferences sp = getActivity().getPreferences(getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);
            mTank = sp.getInt("tank", 2);
            Log.d(TAG, "Loaded data: tank = " + String.valueOf(mTank));
        }
    
        // We're being destroyed. It's important to dispose of the helper here!
        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();

            // very important:
            Log.d(TAG, "Destroying helper.");
            if (mHelper != null) {
                mHelper.dispose();
                mHelper = null;
            }
        }
        
        // Listener that's called when we finish querying the items and
        // subscriptions we own
        IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
            public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result,
                    Inventory inventory) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory finished.");

                // Have we been disposed of in the meantime? If so, quit.
                if (mHelper == null)
                    return;

                // Is it a failure?
                if (result.isFailure()) {
                    complain(getString(R.string.failed_to_query_inventory) + result);
                    return;
                }

                Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory was successful.");

                /*
                 * Check for items we own. Notice that for each purchase, we check
                 * the developer payload to see if it's correct! See
                 * verifyDeveloperPayload().
                 */

                // Do we have the premium upgrade?
                Purchase premiumPurchase = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_PREMIUM);
                mIsPremium = (premiumPurchase != null && verifyDeveloperPayload(premiumPurchase));
                Log.d(TAG, "User is " + (mIsPremium ? "PREMIUM" : "NOT PREMIUM"));

                // Do we have the infinite gas plan?
                Purchase infiniteGasPurchase = inventory
                        .getPurchase(SKU_INFINITE_GAS);
                mSubscribedToInfiniteGas = (infiniteGasPurchase != null && verifyDeveloperPayload(infiniteGasPurchase));
                Log.d(TAG, "User "
                        + (mSubscribedToInfiniteGas ? "HAS" : "DOES NOT HAVE")
                        + " infinite gas subscription.");
                if (mSubscribedToInfiniteGas)
                    mTank = TANK_MAX;

                // Check for gas delivery -- if we own gas, we should fill up the
                // tank immediately
                Purchase gasPurchase = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_GAS);
                if (gasPurchase != null && verifyDeveloperPayload(gasPurchase)) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "We have gas. Consuming it.");
                    mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(SKU_GAS),
                            mConsumeFinishedListener);
                    return;
                }

                updateUi();
                setWaitScreen(false);
                Log.d(TAG, "Initial inventory query finished; enabling main UI.");
            }
        };
        
        /** Verifies the developer payload of a purchase. */
        boolean verifyDeveloperPayload(Purchase p) {
            String payload = p.getDeveloperPayload();

            /*
             * TODO: verify that the developer payload of the purchase is correct.
             * It will be the same one that you sent when initiating the purchase.
             * 
             * WARNING: Locally generating a random string when starting a purchase
             * and verifying it here might seem like a good approach, but this will
             * fail in the case where the user purchases an item on one device and
             * then uses your app on a different device, because on the other device
             * you will not have access to the random string you originally
             * generated.
             * 
             * So a good developer payload has these characteristics:
             * 
             * 1. If two different users purchase an item, the payload is different
             * between them, so that one user's purchase can't be replayed to
             * another user.
             * 
             * 2. The payload must be such that you can verify it even when the app
             * wasn't the one who initiated the purchase flow (so that items
             * purchased by the user on one device work on other devices owned by
             * the user).
             * 
             * Using your own server to store and verify developer payloads across
             * app installations is recommended.
             */

            return true;
        }
        
        // Callback for when a purchase is finished
        IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
            public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Purchase finished: " + result + ", purchase: "
                        + purchase);

                // if we were disposed of in the meantime, quit.
                if (mHelper == null)
                    return;

                if (result.isFailure()) {
                    complain(getString(R.string.error_purchase) + result);
                    setWaitScreen(false);
                    return;
                }
                if (!verifyDeveloperPayload(purchase)) {
                    complain(getString(R.string.error_purchase_authenitcity_failed));
                    setWaitScreen(false);
                    return;
                }

                Log.d(TAG, "Purchase successful.");

                if (purchase.getSku().equals(SKU_GAS)) {
                    // bought 1/4 tank of gas. So consume it.
                    Log.d(TAG, "Purchase is gas. Starting gas consumption.");
                    mHelper.consumeAsync(purchase, mConsumeFinishedListener);
                } else if (purchase.getSku().equals(SKU_PREMIUM)) {
                    // bought the premium upgrade!
                    Log.d(TAG, "Purchase is premium upgrade. Congratulating user.");
                    alert(getString(R.string.thank_you_updgraing_premium));
                    mIsPremium = true;
                    updateUi();
                    setWaitScreen(false);
                } else if (purchase.getSku().equals(SKU_INFINITE_GAS)) {
                    // bought the infinite gas subscription
                    Log.d(TAG, "Infinite gas subscription purchased.");
                    alert("Thank you for subscribing to infinite gas!");
                    mSubscribedToInfiniteGas = true;
                    mTank = TANK_MAX;
                    updateUi();
                    setWaitScreen(false);
                }
            }
        };

        // Called when consumption is complete
        IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener mConsumeFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnConsumeFinishedListener() {
            public void onConsumeFinished(Purchase purchase, IabResult result) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Consumption finished. Purchase: " + purchase
                        + ", result: " + result);

                // if we were disposed of in the meantime, quit.
                if (mHelper == null)
                    return;

                // We know this is the "gas" sku because it's the only one we
                // consume,
                // so we don't check which sku was consumed. If you have more than
                // one
                // sku, you probably should check...
                if (result.isSuccess()) {
                    // successfully consumed, so we apply the effects of the item in
                    // our
                    // game world's logic, which in our case means filling the gas
                    // tank a bit
                    Log.d(TAG, "Consumption successful. Provisioning.");
                    mTank = mTank == TANK_MAX ? TANK_MAX : mTank + 1;
                    saveData();
                    alert("You filled 1/4 tank. Your tank is now "
                            + String.valueOf(mTank) + "/4 full!");
                } else {
                    complain("Error while consuming: " + result);
                }
                updateUi();
                setWaitScreen(false);
                Log.d(TAG, "End consumption flow.");
            }
        };
        
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult(" + requestCode + "," + resultCode + ","
                    + data);
            if (mHelper == null)
                return;

            // Pass on the activity result to the helper for handling
            if (!mHelper.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
                // not handled, so handle it ourselves (here's where you'd
                // perform any handling of activity results not related to in-app
                // billing...
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult handled by IABUtil.");
            }
        }
        
        

    
    //In app billing method end here
```

My products are `Managed products` in developer account `In-app Products`

[image]

**EDIT:**

When I use `android.test.purchased` as a `SKU` then it works fine and as I change my `sku` with my `product_id` then it giving me `Error Authentication is required. You need to sign into your Google Account.`

Comment: Do you test it on a real device with a valid Google Account activated on that device?

Comment: @beworker yes I have tested on real device as well downloaded apk from playstore too

Comment: How about trying this solution out? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w9BU4Zptc2E

Comment: @beworker that also didn't worked.

Comment: Does it work if you just makes a Google example clone, along with all the IAPs defined in the example? It will help narrow down the possible sources of error.

Comment: Another idea would be to go into My account in Google Play app and make sure the right account is selected there.

Comment: It has only one account and that account is added as a tester in google group.

Comment: @NakAndroidDev:
I have stuck on same issue,Do you have any solution for it.
My Question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30122823/authentication-required-error-while-in-app-purchase-android

Comment: @Pankaj No not yet still looking for one. If you got some then do let me know too.

Comment: @NakAndroidDev Any luck yet. I'm facing similar issue.

Comment: @NakAndroidDev Did you solve the problem? I am stuck in the same problem. My app is Published to PROD, I have the same SKU in App and Play Store, and I tried purchasing from my friend's device which had the app downloaded from Play Store. Doesn't work still now. :-(

Comment: Your app should be live on Play store before testing inApp purchase. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Please make sure your product id on playstore for in app purchase which is "test_product" you should use the same sku in your code. And if you change the sku from your application, then all that possible sku names must exists on PlayStore as in-app Products. I once run into this problem and the reason was my SKU item was not exists on Google Playstore in-app products i just add it on Playstore and it was resolved.

Comment: I have using same SKU `test_product`, please check image above `Edit` in above question.

Comment: I didn't realize I was sending wrong SKU. Sending correct SKU fixed it. But I am surprised how misleading was the error message. Google's in-app and billing api, sample codes and documentation is shamefully broken at every level, not to mention the debugging nightmare. And its like this for years. I don't understand the 'super smart' people they hire, why don't they put a couple of them to fix it once and for all.

Answer (score 2):

[Android IAB Error - Authentication required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27920743/android-iab-error-authentication-required)

It seems that you need to publish the APK. I stuck with this problem too.

Comment: It's published in Alpha on developer console

Comment: can i test with different app which is developed locally and create in-app products in different app?

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit of a longshot, but your "Google Play store" app could be malfunctioning.

I have a report from a customer that he cannot make an In-App purchase and he is getting this same error. I also know that we are still getting purchases. So I don't think you necessarily configured anything wrong. IAB v3 could simply be malfunctioning with your "Google Play Store" app.

Try going to Settings open the Application manager and choose the "Google Play store" application in the list, and click on "Uninstall updates" button which appears there. Next try to do the purchase again. If your old Google Play application supports In-App billing v3 it will work. If it doesn't, try to update the "Google Play store" app again, perhaps you will get a newer/different version of the store app and you will be able to make the purchase.

As an alternative you can try and configure a second test device with a different Google account... or ask a friend to join a beta test group and make a test purchase.

I am not really happy with IAB v3. It feels a little clunky. V2 had fewer features but felt solid.

Comment: I have already tried this solution with different devices but it give me same result when I am using my original product id instead of test fake product id SKU.

Comment: Have you tried resetting your Google Play app as well?

I don't think the test product SKU goes through the entire loop and talks to the server. It just talks to the local Google Play app. So no authentication is in play. This means it's unlikely a SKU issue.

Comment: yes I have tried factory reset even with single google account still I am not able to